# Powerapps - How to Audit Trail?

Tags: archive, audit, audit-trail, powerapps

How would you do to implement Audit Trail eg. add User Action(edit, new, delete, print), OldValue and NewValue in a separate "Audit Trail" table? Something like this:

```
 ID | DATE    | USERNAME | FORMNAME | ACTION | FIELDNAME | OLDVALUE | NEWVALUE 
 01    180513   user       form1      edit      Risk         Low       High
```

Old values must not be overwritten and I am kind of a stuck there because "patch" overwrites old values...

Answer (score 1):

One option may be to confirm each change.

Example:

- If user changes an auditable field, show confirmation popup.
- Use the `OnSelect` Property of the "Confirm" button to write a *new* line to the Collection/Data Source
- [Use the `Defaults` line in your `Patch` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-patch#overview) to APPEND this line to the Collection/Data Source each time rather than overwriting it.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! That could be one way to do it.